# How to have IntelliJ automatically generate JAXB source from Maven when making a module

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jaxb

I have a Maven project that uses JAXB to generate source code from a XSD.  I'd like to import this project into IntelliJ as a module, and have IntelliJ be smart enough to generate the source during Make.

The relevant chunk of my pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-jaxb-content</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>*.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This works great command-line.  However, when I import the project into IntelliJ, it will not actually generate the source.  I can manually generate the files by highlighting the XSD and choosing `Tools -> JAXB -> Generate Java Code From Xml Schema Using JAXB...`  But I'd like that to happen automatically when I select `Make Project` or `Make Module`.  This is because I have *several* projects that use JAXB and I don't want to manually do this for each one.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you go to Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment->Compiler->Annotation Processors there is settings in here to configure an annotation processor that I believe is run when you do a Make Project or Make Module. I think IntelliJ should pick up on these settings from your pom but it is possible it doesn't automatically.

Comment: Another option might be to run the generate-sources task with a maven run configuration. This should generate the proper sources as required.